# Is there a way to retrieve the query of a stored procedure after it's been replaced?

Tags: google-bigquery

If one were to replace the entire body of a stored procedure with a CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE statement, is there a way to retrieve the previous version?

This proc is run nightly as part of a series of jobs in the cloud scheduler. Looking at the results of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT, the 'query' field shows me the proc, but not the query.

And for the record, it wasn't me!

Comment: You can find the query from Logs Explorer. To do so run the following query in Logs Explorer:`resource.type="bigquery_resource"
"CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE $NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET" 
severity="INFO"`.If you expand the log payload, in the serviceData field you will find the query in the query subfield.

Comment: Glad to hear the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the query from `Logs Explorer`. To do so run the following query in Logs Explorer:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource" "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE $NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET"  severity="INFO"
```

If you expand the `log payload`, in the `serviceData field` you will find the `query` in the query subfield.